# LocalStorage only storing last entered data

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, local-storage, web-inspector

I am using LocalStorage to store username and password on an app I'm building with PhoneGap for iOS. When I run the app on my iPad, and I enter the username and password, close the app, then open again to enter another username and password. When I connect my iPad with my Macbook and open Safari Web inspector to inspect my app running on the iPad, when I go to "Storage -> localStorage" within the inspector, only the last entered username and password is displayed, but the first set of username and password I entered is no where to be found. Anyone have any ideas as to why this happens?

js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

function onDeviceReady() {
document.getElementById("btnSave").addEventListener("click",saveData,false);
document.getElementById("btnGet").addEventListener("click",getData,false);
}

    function saveData(){
        var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
        window.localStorage.setItem("uname", username);
        window.localStorage.setItem("pass", password);
        alert("Your data is stored");
    }
    function getData(){
        var output="Your username is " + window.localStorage.getItem("uname") + "and your password is " + window.localStorage.getItem("pass");
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = output;
    }
</script>
```

html:

```
    User Name: <input type ="text" id="username" /><br />
    Password: <input type="text" id="password" /><br />
    <button id="btnSave"> Save Data </button>
    <button id="btnGet"> Get Data </button>
    <div id="result"></div>
```

I've tried looking everywhere around the web inspector but still couldn't find where my first set of stored data went. Is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: LocalStorage store only key value pairs, if you do setItem the previous Item is overriden

Comment: The thing you are doing is wrong that is storing username and passwords in localstorage,there are ways you can overcome this overwrite `bug` but tell me how are you going to validate those users ?

Comment: I am just using username as a practice, what I wanted to store is actually button clicks, but the examples I found online are based on usernames so I thought I'd see if it works and I can then integrate it into button clicks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
var localObject = [];
var testObject = {userName : "firstUser", password : "password1"};
localObject.push(testObject);
localStorage.setItem("userDetails", JSON.stringify(localObject));
console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userDetails")));

//for second time 
var testObject = {userName : "secondUser", password : "password2"};
localObject.push(testObject);
localStorage.setItem("userDetails", JSON.stringify(localObject));
console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userDetails")));
```

Every time you try to store the user details, fetch the local storage, push the user details as an object into the array.

Comment: Why did you post two answers?

Comment: thanks but it still overwrites the username. I'm now just focusing on saving the usernames and if it works I can then integrate into password etc. My code: var localObject = [];
            var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
            localObject.push(username);
            window.localStorage.setItem("uname", JSON.stringify(username));
            console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("uname")));
            alert("Your data is stored");

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage just stores key value pairs. To store more than one value use a workaround:

```
str=localStorage.getItem("users");
if(str==""){
str="[]";
}
users=JSON.parse(str);
//users contains an array now
users.push("John");
//add a user
localStorage.setItem("users",JSON.stringify(users));
//create json and store it again
```

Comment: Thanks. I've changed my code to: function saveData(){
            var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
            var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
            var date = new Date();
            window.localStorage.setItem("date", JSON.stringify(date));
            window.localStorage.setItem("uname", JSON.stringify(username));
            window.localStorage.setItem("pass", JSON.stringify(password));
            alert("Your data is stored");
        } but it still overwrites the value when viewed in web inspector

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var localObject = [];
localObject = localStorage.getItem("userDetails");
var testObject = {userName : "firstUser", password : "password1"};
var testArray = localObject.push(testObject);
localStorage.setItem("userDetails", JSON.stringify(testArray));
//to fetch the data
localStorage.getItem("userDetails");
console.log (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userDetails")));

//for second time 
var localObject = localStorage.getItem("userDetails");
var testObject = {userName : "secondUser", password : "password2"};
testArray = localObject.push(testObject);
localStorage.setItem("userDetails", JSON.stringify(testArray));
console.log (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userDetails")));
```